# Get info about user browser

Tags: jsp, browser, user-agent

I'm trying to get info about user's browser in jsf and example in book is some sort of weird. They offer to check with code

```
String userAgent=request.getHeader("user-agent");
String browser="unknown";

if (userAgent !=null)
{
    if (userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")>-1)
        browser="MS Internet Explorer";
    else if (userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")>-1)
        browser="Mozilla Firefox";
    else if (userAgent.indexOf("Opera")>-1)
        browser="Opera";
    else if (userAgent.indexOf("Chrome")>-1)
        browser="Google Chrome";
    else if (userAgent.indexOf("Safari")>-1)
        browser="Apple Safari";
}   
out.println("<br/>and your browser is "+browser+"<br/>");
```

and useragent gives me

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36.

So if I change the order of checking browser names, it may give me weird result

```
if (userAgent !=null)
{
    if (userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")>-1)
        browser="MS Internet Explorer";
    else if (userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")>-1)
        browser="Mozilla Firefox";
    else if (userAgent.indexOf("Opera")>-1)
        browser="Opera";
    else if (userAgent.indexOf("Safari")>-1)
        browser="Apple Safari";
    else if (userAgent.indexOf("Chrome")>-1)
        browser="Google Chrome";
}
```

as if I am using Safari. Is this code really working, or maybe there are more right ways to check user's browser?

Comment: This code is correct. Here you have user agent strings for Safari: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/. In your first example the order of browser is correct.

Comment: so it means that order of checking matters very much?

Comment: I guess I got it, Chrome's user agent isn't "independent" from Safari, so it must come first, not to mix up with it. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, the order in this case dose matter :)